# Загрузка картинок из папки assets в imageView используя библиотеку пикассо

Tags: android, picasso

В приложении я использую sqlile, в которой одна колонка это картинки. В таблице просто хранится название в виде "image1.ipg" сами картинки лежат в папке assets.

Адаптер, где все происходит

```
    public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteAdapter.VersesViewHolder> {

    class VersesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView tv_title;
        private final ImageView image;

        private VersesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Verses> verses;

    public FavoriteAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public VersesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
        return new VersesViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VersesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Verses current = verses.get(position);
        holder.tv_title.setText(current.title);
   //     Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(current.image);


    }

    public void setVerses(List<Verses> verses) {
        this.verses = verses;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (verses != null)
            return verses.size();
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Закомментированная строчка, это пример из документации. Не могу разобраться как вместо ссылки на конкретную картину ("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png") написать код загружающий картинку соответствующего item-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте так:
    `String imgName = "file:///android_asset/image"+position;`

или так:
    `String imgName = "file:///android_asset/"+current.getImgName();`

После чего:
    `Picasso.get().load(imgName).into(holder.image);`

Можно сразу прописать полный путь в `Verses` и делать так: `Picasso.get().load(current.getImage()).into(holder.image);`